# Laravel - Get additional attributes of Many to Many table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I got the following tables

- actors

  1. id
  2. name
- stats

  1. id
  2. name
- actor_stat

  1. actor_id
  2. stat_id
  3. quantity

I want, given an actor's name, take all the quantities associated.

Actor model:

```php
class Actor extends Model
{
    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stat', 'actor_stat')->withPivot('quantity');
    }

}
```

Stat model:

```php
class Stat extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'actor_stat')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Query

```php
    public function request(){
        $actors = Actor::where('name','Jack')->first();

        $stat = $actors->pivot->quantity; //??

        return response()->json(['actors' => $actors, 'stat' => $stat]);
    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You want to update pivote column?

Comment: I want to get the 'quantity' value. I mean I get a single actor with the first query, after I want all the associations actor-stat and for each the quantity value.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eager loading to load related table like this:

```
$actors = Actor::with('stats')->where('name','Jack')->first();

//do loop foreach actor state then you can access to quantity column

 foreach($actors->states as $state)
   $state->pivot->quantity;
```